# Unauthorized and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 4, column 10

Tags: maven, pom.xml

What does this error mean? I had this error previously too but it went away on its own but now i have tried everything to fix this but it wont go away.

heres my pom.xml file line 4:

```
1...
2...
3...
4   <parent>
5       <groupId>com.company.scs</groupId>
6       <artifactId>common-iaf</artifactId>
7       <version>1.4</version>
8       <relativePath />
9   </parent>
```

what does this mean & how do I fix it?

Comment: can you post your full pom?

Comment: @SurajGautam

my pom.xml is too long, Stackoverflow wont let me upload it